# "No more authentication methods available" Error message ever since entering the wrong password for SSH

Tags: git, authentication, ssh

After joining a new company domain today I had to enter my SSH password to connect to git and commit some changes I made in eclipse. I was misremembering my password and entered the wrong one in enough times to start getting this error:
`"No more authentication methods available"`
My thought is that it's a bad password lockout kind of situation, so I deleted the SSH key and made a new one. I have saved the public key under my profile in the remote server through the GitLab website. That has not worked. Has anyone been here before?

Comment: If you are using the ssh url for git, you need to save the public key in the remote server under your profile, it doesn't need your password. Make sure you add the public of the new key pair you generate. You could check connectivity by doing ssh -vT git@<hostname>. It will give you verbose output and a success message if all OK.

Comment: I have saved the public key under my profile in the remote server through the GitLab website, they don't make you have a password but I used the option of having one. I used that method though and it looks like maybe when I make the new keys the config files weren't updated?

Answer (score 0):

> I used the option of having one

It is a passphrase (`ssh-keygen -P "my pssphrase"`), not a password.

Make sure that:

- the key is the default one (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`)
- the key is added to an `ssh-agent` (since you would need to cache the passphrase)